# message vs mail in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, actionmailer

I ran into an issue where I was trying to apply an after_filter to a mailer in a Rails 3 project.  I included the following code:

```
include AbstractController::Callbacks

after_filter :check_notifications

def welcome(user)
  @user = user

  mail(to: email_with_name(@user.full_name, @user.email),
       subject: 'Get started with your new account!')
end

def check_notifications
  mail.to = mail.to.select { |user_email| User.find_by_email(user_email).receive_notification_emails == true } 
end
```

but this changed the subject of the email to the method name.  So for the welcome mailer, the subject would be 'Welcome' (interesting that it's capitalized too).  If I change the mail.to to message.to this is fixed.  I want to know why one works and the other doesn't when I'm not touching the message in the after_filter.

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem in Rails 4. As soon as I do anything in an after_filter the subject is changed. Is this a bug in ActionMailer? Does anyone know?

Comment: If I return `message` at the end of the filter everything seems to be alright. Looks like this is expected to be returned.